# Can't get Elementary to appear in grub and boot

Tags: grub2, elementary-os

I have grub installed but it won't take Elementary OS. I have no idea how to boot it manually because the option is there to do it manually.

I do know eOS is located on sda5. I also get the /cow error too and for some reason boot repair won't work either.

Answer (score 3):

you have to boot from live cd and type in terminal

```
sudo update-initramfs -u;sudo update-grub;
```

if the problem still exist you have to reinstall grub from the live cd terminal

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt;
sudo GRUB-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda;
sudo update-grub;
```